# Setting all NULL values in a table to ""

Tags: sql, null

is there a way to set all NULL values in a table to ""?

I am selecting a subtable from two tables, selecting specific fields. The output cannot have NULL values and I am trying to generate the results with NULL replaced with "" when necessary.

While I could add IS NUll() parameters to each field, there are ~50 columns and I am trying to avoid manually adding this piece since I will need to create this across a number of iterations.

Is there a broader way to set all NULLs in the table to ""?

```
`select 
IS NULL(a.fieldA, ""), 
IS NULL(b.fieldB, ""),
from DB.TableA a
join DB.TableB b
on a.Identifier = b.Identifier`
```

Comment: No, you have to do it for each _column_.

Comment: Probably not but which DBMS are you using and how are you planning to process the result of the SELECT statement (write it to a table, copy and paste it from the UI, embed the SQL in another tool, etc)?

Comment: What's the problem with nulls? They have a meaning for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is good enough.
Depending on DBMS you might be able to concatenate such queries, using `information_schema.columns` and `information_schema.tables`.
It looks smth like this in MySQL

```
create table test123(i int, x varchar(12), y varchar(12), z numeric(6,2));

select
  concat(
    'select IFNULL(',
    REPLACE(
      group_concat(c.COLUMN_NAME),
      ',',
      ',''''),IFNULL('
    ),
    ','''') from ',
    t.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    '.',
    t.TABLE_NAME,
    ';'
  )
from
  information_schema.tables t
  join information_schema.columns c 
    on t.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG
    and t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
    and t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
where
  t.table_name in ('test123') <-- paste your tables here
group by
  t.TABLE_SCHEMA,
  t.TABLE_NAME;
```

result will be like this. just copy and run.

```
select IFNULL(i,''),IFNULL(z,''),IFNULL(y,''),IFNULL(x,'') from public.test123;
```

Also depending on DBMS you even might be able to execute those queries dynamically. 
Or you can alter your table so that all columns would be non-NULL and with default value of "".